# How can I obtain a sampling of all tweets from a specific time period?

Tags: twitter

I want to gather samplings of all tweets from the past year.  Being able to request tweets from a specific date would be great, but I'll take what I can get.

I do not want to find tweets by a specific user or containing a specific term, just a sampling of all tweets. The [Twitter search API](http://apiwiki.twitter.com/w/page/22554756/Twitter-Search-API-Method%3a-search) claims that a query term is optional, but if I try an empty query like

```
http://search.twitter.com/search.atom
```

as opposed to giving a search term,

```
http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=twitter
```

the response is

```
<hash>
<error>
You must enter a query.
</error>
</hash>
```

If the API really doesn't provide any functionality for this type of query, how can I hack around it?  Are tweet ids roughly sequential by date and can I somehow use this info to grab bunches of tweets centered around an id of a tweet whose date I know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are referencing the obsolete documentation. If you read the [current version](http://dev.twitter.com/doc/get/search) you will find that a `query` is required.

You should also know that the Search API only provides results going back about two weeks. You might be able to find historical data from sites like [infochimps](http://www.infochimps.com/tags/Twitter).

Answer (score 0):

Not useful for historical data, but in case someone stumbles across this question looking for a sampling of all *current* tweets, you want the [streaming API](http://dev.twitter.com/pages/streaming_api_methods).  (This is my first foray into Twitter and I hadn't noticed it.  I only saw the [public timeline](http://dev.twitter.com/doc/get/statuses/public_timeline) method in the normal API.)